# On Exchange Server 2007, how do I allow inbound email from certain servers only?

Tags: email, exchange-2007

On Exchange Server 2007, how do I allow inbound email from certain servers only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Exchange Management Console, under Server Configuration, on the Hub Transport, you should see the Receive connectors,  on the Network tab,  configure the "Receive From Servers" to only the IPs of the servers you want.

Comment: +1, but i think you mean Exchange Management Console. :)

Comment: @Dan -  Correct and edited to reflect.  In my hurry to get the answer posted, my brain swapped it.

Answer (score 2):

See [Configuring Connection Filtering in Exchange 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123943.aspx)